# Use change of variables to compute the integral

Tags: definite-integrals, change-of-variable

A region, D, is bounded by these four curves:
$$y=x^3-4$$
$$y=x^3+4$$
$$x+y=6$$
$$x+y=0$$

I want to compute this integral by using a suitable change of variables:
$$\iint_D(3x^3+3x^2y+x+y) \, dA$$

Just by looking at expressions that repeat themselves I'd guess this could be a feasible change of variables:
$$u=x^3$$
$$v=x+y$$

But I have no idea where to go from here. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've divided $D$ in four areas (look the picture below)

$D_1=\{(x,y)|0\leq x \leq 1,4\leq y\leq x^3+4\}\\
D_2=\{(x,y)|1\leq x \leq 2,4\leq y\leq x+6\}\\
D_3=\{(x,y)|(y-4)^(1/3)\leq x \leq (y+4)^{1/3},y_0\leq y\leq 4\}\\
D_4=\{(x,y)|-y\leq x \leq (y+4)^{1/3},y_1\leq y\leq y_0\}$

Call $f(x,y)=3 x^3 + 3 x^2 y + x + y$

and the integral can  be split in these four parts

$$\int_0^1\int_4^{x^3+4}\,f(x,y) \,dy\,dx+
\int_1^2\int_4^{x+6}\,f(x,y) \,dy\,dx+\\
\int_{y_0}^4\int_{\sqrt[3]{y-4}}^{\sqrt[3]{y+4}}\, f(x,y)\,dx\,dy+
\int_{y_1}^{y_0}\int_{-y}^{\sqrt[3]{y+4}}\,f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Where $y_0$ is the real solution of the equation $x^3-4=-x$

and $y_1$ is the real solution of $x^3+4=-x$

I have got respectively the following values

$$\iint_D(3x^3+3x^2y+x+y)\,dA=3.87+213.4+20.06+101.54\approx 338.87$$

I did my best

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am supposed to solve the integral by using a change of variables... :/